# Необязательный where в ORM Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

День добрый, у меня существует Route::get, в котором необязательные параметры. Как описать метод так, чтобы не пришлось плодить кучу if'ов?  По типу

```
$param1 = $request->input('param1');
$param2 = $request->input('param2');
if($dogovor != null && $phone != null){
    $data = SomethingModel::select('id','param1','param2','param3','param4')
                            ->where('param1','=', $param1)
                            ->where('param2','=', $param2);
}
else($dogovor != null && $phone == null){
//
}
else($dogovor == null && $phone != null){
//
}
```

Comment: `$request->all()` что показывает?

Comment: ```when``` рассматривали?

Comment: @Walfter Спасибо за наводку, то что надо

Comment: @InDevX Не пробовал, но спасибо что за помощь! Решение найдено

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Решение с использованием `when`

```
$param1 = $request->input('param1');
$param2 = $request->input('param2');
$data = SomethingModel::select('id','param1','param2','param3','param4')
        ->when($param1, function ($query, $param1) {
            return $query->where('param1', $param1);
        })
        ->when($param2, function ($query, $param2) {
            return $query->where('param2', $param2);
        })->get();
```